# Delphi выдаёт ошибку "Not enough actual parameters"

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Объясните, что тут не так?????

```
procedure TForm8.tmr1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ...
  Application.MessageBox('Мое сообщение.'); // [Error] Unit8.pas(38): Not enough actual parameters
end;
```

[image: Скриншот ошибки]

Comment: Приведите исходный код целиком. По данной картинке невозможно "поставить диагноз".

Comment: Добавил фото..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод TApplication.MessageBox в Delphi имеет вид

```
function MessageBox(const Text: PChar; const Caption: PChar; Flags: Longint = MB_OK): Integer;
```

По вашей "фотке" трудно что-либо разглядеть, но набор параметров при вызове явно не соответствует описанию метода. О чем, кстати, говорится в сообщении об ошибке на первой картинке.

Comment: Спасибо))))))))